# SVN is continuously getting hit if username & password are not supplied in svn ant file

Tags: svn, ant

I have an SVNANT file which is receiving svn username & password as input and used to copy a file from trunk to tags. It is working fine if we provide username & password. But the problem occurs when we do not pass username & password. I mean when username & password are kept blank the ant keep on sending request to SVN and svn becomes busy due to it. Can anyone tell me the cause and solution for this problem??
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Now the same problem is happening again with Jenkins hitting SVN with wrong credentials. It goes on hitting the svn again and again. It sent 2000 requests per minute into SVN and svn went down. Has anybody encounter this kind of problem with SVN?

Also as we all know this problem does not happen with svn client. But it happens with first SVNANT and now with jenkins trying to connect with SVN server with wrong credentials.

Comment: Is there a reason the username and password are being kept blank?

Comment: yes if username and password are left blank the same problem exists in addition to above problem.